# Read value of Hidden Field inside ng-repeat in html table binding

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a html table and data is binding from angular js.
The structure is like that

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in List| filter: { MachineType: 'Physical' }">


     <td>{{item.MachineType}}</td>


</tr>
```

I want to pass the filter value dynamically from html hidden field which is set dynamically.

How I read the Html hidden field value here and pass in filter..

Thanks

Comment: just pass filter(item.MachineType)

Comment: it is not clear what you want

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to filter some data based on another dynamic field.

Here is an example of how you would filter based on search query.

```
<p><input type="hidden" ng-model="test"></p>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in names | filter : test">
    {{ x }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

You can make custom filters as well. The question you proposed was a little broad so I think this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_filters.asp) can help with a myriad of filter queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can do set **ng-model** on the **hidden element** and then pass it to the **filter**. Below is one of the simplest way you can do it.

```
<input type="hidden" ng-model="myMachineTypw" />

<tr ng-repeat="item in List| filter: { MachineType: myMachineTypw }">
     <td>{{item.MachineType}}</td>
</tr>
```

Another way is, you said you are setting the value of hidden dynamically right? Then you don't even need the hidden element, just update the value of **$scope.myMachineType** and use that **myMachineType** as shown in above example and **remove the hidden element**.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .controller('myCtrl', myCtrl);

    myCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

    function myCtrl ($scope) {
        $scope.myMachineType = "anyValue";
    }
</script>

<tr ng-repeat="item in List| filter: { MachineType: myMachineType }">
     <td>{{item.MachineType}}</td>
</tr>
```

Here is working example:

```js
angular.module('myApp', []);

angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('myAppController', myAppController);

myAppController.$inject = ['$scope'];

function myAppController ($scope) {

    $scope.processing = true;

    $scope.init = init;

    function init () {
        $scope.List = [
          {'name':'Item 1', 'MachineType': 'Type1'},
          {'name':'Item 2', 'MachineType': 'Type2'},
          {'name':'Item 3', 'MachineType': 'Type3'},
          {'name':'Item 4', 'MachineType': 'Type2'},
          {'name':'Item 5', 'MachineType': 'Type1'},
          {'name':'Item 6', 'MachineType': 'Type1'},
          {'name':'Item 7', 'MachineType': 'Type3'},
          {'name':'Item 8', 'MachineType': 'Type1'},
          {'name':'Item 9', 'MachineType': 'Type3'},
          {'name':'Item 10', 'MachineType': 'Type3'}
        ];

        $scope.setType = function (x) {
            if ( x ) {
                $scope.myMachineType = "Type"+x;
            } else {
                $scope.myMachineType = "";
            }
        }

    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myAppController" ng-init="init();">
    <button ng-click="setType();">Show All</button>
    <button ng-click="setType(1);">Type 1</button>
    <button ng-click="setType(2);">Type 2</button>
    <button ng-click="setType(3);">Type 3</button>
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="i in List | filter: { MachineType: myMachineType }">
             <td>{{i.name}} : {{i.MachineType}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```